# Draw line with mouse in JPanel on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel

I need to draw a line in JPanel with mouse, clicking two points in panel. First click would be the start of the line, and second click would be the end of the line.

[This is my programm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZbN4.png)

I have something like this:

```
    private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Graphics g = this.jPanel1.getGraphics();

    int x = evt.getX();
    int y = evt.getY();

    g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
}
```

But it only draws pixel.
[Line with coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiHlb.png)
I need something like this, but just drawing it with mouse clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're drawing a line from (x, y) to (x, y) which is why you're getting just a single pixel.  You need to capture the co-ordinates of the first click, and then draw the line on the second click.

```
private int startX = -1;
private int startY = -1;

private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if (startX == -1 && startY == -1) {
        startX = evt.getX();
        startY = evt.getY();
    } else {
        Graphics g = this.jPanel1.getGraphics();
        g.drawLine(startX, startY, 
                   evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        // reset the start point
        startX = -1;
        startY = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: But what do I define as x,y?

Comment: `private int startX = -1;
private int startY = -1;` 

Can I define these somehow different? Like inside the private void?

Comment: No, because you need them to persist between method calls. If you define them in jPanel1MouseClicked, the variables will go out of scope when the method exits.

Comment: `private int x0 = 0;
private int y0 = 0;
    private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (x0 == 0 && y0 == 0) {
            x0 = evt.getX();
            y0 = evt.getY();
        } else {
            Graphics g = this.jPanel1.getGraphics();
            g.drawLine(x0, y0, evt.getX(), evt.getY());
            x0 = 0;
            y0 = 0;
        }
    } `

So I wanted to ask, If i can get this code be working by brezenhema algorithm, not with built-in function?

Answer (score 1):

From the doc

> Draws a line, using the current color, between the points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) in this graphics context's coordinate system.

In your case x1=x2 and y1=y2, that's why your line is 1 pixel long. After each click you must record the coordinates of your click so that you can use them as the origin of the line for the next click.